# Как связать инпуты с ползунком range slider для вывода результата?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Можно ли как-то связать значения инпутов `from` и `to` range slider при их редактировании (ввод значений в поля) с функцией `getValues(values)`, вычисляющей разницу `to - from`?

Пример на [codepen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/rLeybE?editors=0010)

- На данный момент происходит вычисление только при перетаскивании ползунков.
- Меняю ползунки слайдера - вычисляется total, ввожу в поля input свои значения - не вычисляется total )

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');

  // ---------------------------------- Range slider jq ui
  $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.filter__slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.filter__slider-input-from'),
      to = container.find('.filter__slider-input-to');

    from.change(function() {
      $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 0, from.val());
    });

    to.change(function() {
      $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 1, to.val());
    });

    $this.slider({
      range: true,
      min: min,
      max: max,
      values: [min, max],
      slide: function(event, ui) { // При каждом перемещении
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(ui.values[0]);
        to.val(ui.values[1]);
        getValues(ui.values);
      },
      // change: function(event, ui) {                    // В конце перетаскивания    
      //   getValues(ui.values);
      // },
      create: function() { // При создании виджета
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(values[0]);
        to.val(values[1]);

        //getValues();
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) { // При завершении перетаскивания
        getValues(ui.values);
      }
    });
  });

  function getValues(values) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() {
      var values = $(this).slider("option", "values");
      var dif = values[1] - values[0];
      total += dif;
    });

    $("#totals").text(total);
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="300"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Total: <span id="totals">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rom-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">отправить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При установке свойства *values* происходит событие *change*, поэтому его стоит раскомментировать и все заработает.

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');

  // ---------------------------------- Range slider jq ui
  $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.filter__slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.filter__slider-input-from'),
      to = container.find('.filter__slider-input-to');

    from.change(function() {
      $this.slider('values', 0, from.val());
    });

    to.change(function() {
      $this.slider('values', 1, to.val());
    });

    $this.slider({
      range: true,
      min: min,
      max: max,
      values: [min, max],
      slide: function(event, ui) { // При каждом перемещении
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(ui.values[0]);
        to.val(ui.values[1]);
        getValues(ui.values);
      },
      change: function(event, ui) { // В конце перетаскивания    
        console.log('change');
        getValues(ui.values);
      },
      create: function() { // При создании виджета
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(values[0]);
        to.val(values[1]);

        //getValues();
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) { // При завершении перетаскивания
        getValues(ui.values);
      }
    });
  });

  function getValues(values) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() {
      var values = $(this).slider("option", "values");
      var dif = values[1] - values[0];
      total += dif;
    });

    $("#totals").text(total);
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="300"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Total: <span id="totals">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rom-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">отправить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Странно почему у меня с ним не работало и я его закомментровала!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, потому что он вызывается только в конце движения, то есть если бы был только этот обработчик значения не менялись бы пока пользователь двигает туда сюда